# RackSpace and Centrify

Tags: active-directory, rackspace-cloud, rackspace

I'm not sure if anybody else hosts with RackSpace and/or uses Centrify, but if you do, maybe you can answer my question. My group would like to control RackSpace (myrackspace.com) login portal with Centrify (Active Directory) credentials, e.g., tie our AD accounts to RackSpace. I currently have a discussion up on RackSpace's "forums" but it's not getting any activity. I realize this is a pretty general question, but I will gladly supply any details that are lacking.

Thanks a bunch,

-Brian

Comment: Brian, this question is very ambiguous. I use Centrify, in my experience "it just works", and works very well at that. But how that relates to your Rackspace logins is unclear from the question.

Answer (score 1):

That's not going to happen.  Rackspace's portal doesn't tie to their AD platform at all, so there's no way that you'll be able to tie your AD to the portal.

Comment: I don't see the reason why that should not happen. Given Brian's question, it is possible in several ways:

* install their own AD server in Rackspace, let the other server use the AD credential
* connect the AD server in Brian's company to the UNIX/Linux server's Centrify through ADFS/SAML

Your answer is based on connecting to Rackspace AD, while Brian's question is about connecting to their company's AD ("our AD accounts").

Comment: Given that he is talking about modifying the my.rackspace.com customer portal to work off of AD accounts there's no way that RackSpace is going to allow that to happen off of his domain accounts.